# Instruct Firefox (or any browser than can) to print data on a webpage to next page?

Tags: firefox, browser, printing, html, css

For example I have the following HTML page

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

This should be printed in the first page

<!-- Special code to print anything below this line to next page -->

This should be printed in the second page

</body>
</html>
```

Is there a special code like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far as I know, there is no special code to control displayed "pages" because "next page" has different meaning on an iPhone, on a 10" tablet and on a dual 24" screen PC.

I believe `page-break-before="always|auto|"` can be used in CSS2 to affect printing of HTML.